# No overload matches this call - width

Tags: reactjs, material-ui, react-typescript

I'm trying to rewrite this React JS into typescript: https://codesandbox.io/s/pedantic-violet-yklku

I get error when I try to change this line:

```
            <Grid
                spacing={0}
                container
                direction="row"
                xs={3}
                className={classes2.color}
                width={2}
                style={{ height: "100%", overflow: "auto" }}
            >
```

I get error:

```
TS2769: No overload matches this call.   Overload 1 of 2, '(props: { component: ElementType<any>; } & { alignContent?: GridContentAlignment | undefined; alignItems?: GridItemsAlignment | undefined; ... 13 more ...; zeroMinWidth?: boolean | undefined; } & CommonProps<...> & Pick<...>): Element', gave the following error.     Property 'component' is missing in type '{ children: Element[]; spacing: 0; container: true; direction: "row"; xs: 3; className: string; width: number; style: { height: string; overflow: "auto"; }; }' but required in type '{ component: ElementType<any>; }'.   Overload 2 of 2, '(props: DefaultComponentProps<GridTypeMap<{}, "div">>): Element', gave the following error.     Type '{ children: Element[]; spacing: 0; container: true; direction: "row"; xs: 3; className: string; width: number; style: { height: string; overflow: "auto"; }; }' is not assignable to type 'IntrinsicAttributes & { alignContent?: GridContentAlignment | undefined; alignItems?: GridItemsAlignment | undefined; ... 13 more ...; zeroMinWidth?: boolean | undefined; } & CommonProps<...> & Pick<...>'.       Property 'width' does not exist on type 'IntrinsicAttributes & { alignContent?: GridContentAlignment | undefined; alignItems?: GridItemsAlignment | undefined; ... 13 more ...; zeroMinWidth?: boolean | undefined; } & CommonProps<...> & Pick<...>'.
```

When I remove `width` it's working. Do you know alternative way to set max fixed width for Grid?

Comment: `Grid` doesn't have a `width` property, so it isn't having any effect in the JS you're trying to rewrite -- just remove it.

Answer (score 1):

You can add `maxWidth: "350px"` or whatever value you want to the `style` property. However, the `xs` and similar size properties are designed to manage width based on viewport sizes.